# Invoking delegate cannot convert void to system.delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

in `Main` I have `public void playbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` and I'm trying to call that from a different class with Invoke(). My second class looks like

```
class KeyBinds
{
    public delegate void Del(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public static void CheckKey(int key)
    {

         Del handler = (Application.OpenForms[0] as Main).playbutton_Click;
         (Application.OpenForms[0] as Main).Invoke(handler(null,null));

    }
```

But the handler(null,null) returns an error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.delegate'

Comment: "handler" propably expects another delegate as the first argument. And you gave it null. Wich is why it complained. | That or handler returns void, but Invoke expects a Delegate.

Comment: You need to pass `handler` to Invoke, followed by its arguments: `.Invoke(handler, null, EventArgs.Empty)`. Invoke will then call that delegate with those arguments. Instead, you're *calling* handler and passing `handler`'s *return value* to Invoke. `handler` is declared as void, so there is no return value. Certainly not a delegate. You might want to pass the actual value of `Main.playbutton` to Invoke() for the first (`sender`) argument, where I passed `null`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That was it, thanks.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Very well observed. Please post this as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

quoted by user
15ee8f99-57ff-4f92-890c-b56153. They did not post this as an answer so I'm putting this here because it was very helpful and worked for me as well and will improve visibility:

You need to pass `handler` to `Invoke`, followed by its arguments: `.Invoke(handler, null, EventArgs.Empty)`. Invoke will then call that delegate with those arguments. Instead, you're calling `handler` and passing handler's return value to `Invoke`. `handler` is declared as void, so there is no return value. Certainly not a delegate. You might want to pass the actual value of `Main.playbutton` to `Invoke()` for the first (`sender`) argument, where I passed `null`.